# C# Read Data from Open Excel File

Tags: c#

Using C# Selenium, how would I read/write data from an Excel file that is already open on the user's machine? I've searched the other answers here and only see how to open the Excel and start reading. Am I able to connect to a file that is already open and read/write to it? In my case I would know the exact file name just not the file location.

Comment: what if the excel file doesn't contain any date field but just numeric and text fields?

Answer (score 0):

If you open your File-Explorer and go into the Folder of the Excel-File you will see a lock-File when one other user has opened the Document.
This will be on all Office Documents.

In normal mode only one (the first) User can open a Office Document and write in it. So no other User can write ...

But there will be a Function that allowes multiple-Users to work in the same time on one Office Document. So multiple User can open and do changes over the day. It will update for a single User directly on save with the modifications from the other Users.

I dont know the english name of this function, but it should be something like -Approve Document-

Maybe this link will be helpfull ... It is in german and you can translate it.

[Excel-Freigeben-Zusammenarbeiten](https://www.computerbild.de/artikel/cb-Tipps-Software-Excel-fuer-mehrere-Benutzer-freigeben-31569745.html)

Comment: |I dont know the english name of this function": In English that is:  [Share workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1grgT.png)  (From the menu "Review"/"Share Workbook")  (Microsoft link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/use-shared-workbook )

Comment: Or in Dutch: "Gegevens/Werkmap delen": https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnDbm.png